# Page jumps to top when clicking new tab (jQuery Tabs)

Tags: jquery, jquery-tabs

I am using jquery tabs with ajax.

Html:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a id='tab-1' href="/get-1.htm">1</a></li>
        <li><a id='tab-2' href="/get-2.htm">2</a></li>
        <li><a id='tab-3' href="/get-3.htm">3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({
    beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
        ui.jqXHR.error(function() {
            ui.panel.html
            (
                "bla bla bla";
            );
        });
    }
});
```

Gif showing the problem:
`<!----------------------- IMAGE START ----------------------->`

[image]

`<!----------------------- IMAGE END ----------------------->`

For more smoothier check this link (select mp4): [click me](http://gyazo.com/c6117187a397ec856a326534289beb6b)

I clicked 2nd tab, page jumped to top. Another example:
`<!----------------------- IMAGE START ----------------------->`

[image]

`<!----------------------- IMAGE END ----------------------->`

[more smoothier](http://gyazo.com/b7b2275d6c0ed8fe88cf8356879049d8)

Note (2nd example) that if I already opened tab earlier (was on 1st, pressed 2, jumped, pressed 1, no jump).

How I can solve this problem?

**UPDATE**

Sad, but example https://jqueryui.com/tabs/ is working fine :( There are no same bug.

Comment: I would try adding something like `[event].preventDefault();` to whatever function is triggered by your tab links.

Comment: I don't call any functions by myself.

Comment: why do your anchor tags have id's?

Comment: You mean `<a>` tags? When page is loaded, I want to show tab depending on GET parameter. So I have script which do this. Script: `$("#tab-"+type+"").trigger("click");` `type` has been got from the query.

Comment: I don't know if it's related, but you also have a syntax error. This line: `"bla bla bla";` should not have the trailing semicolon.

Comment: Is your address bar changing when you click on a tab?

Comment: @beercodebeer oops. I don't have this `;` in normal code. I maked this mistake there, on so. Ty. I will edit.

Comment: @KevinB Nope. I thinked about `#` (hashcode) too :)

Comment: Then i believe this is purely a css problem. the page's height changes such that it appears to scroll to the top.

Comment: See this fiddle for a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/4uhjF/ Start by scrolling down in tab one, then clicking on tab2. Because the height of the tab is smaller, the height of the page changes enough to cause it to scroll to the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on a tab that has less content than the current tab, the overall height of the page changes which can affect the scroll position of the page. One way to "fix" this is to use the heightStyle option and set it to "auto", however I'm not entirely sure how that is going to work with ajax tabs.

http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-heightStyle

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({ heightStyle: "fill" });
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/4uhjF/ Click on tab one, scroll down until you can't see the h1, then click on tab 2. Because tab2 has far less content, the height of the page changes enough to cause a jump to top. The only way around this is to ensure that the content of all tabs have a similar height, or to set the height to a specific number and use scrolling for anything larger than that height. heightStyle: "fill" would be the best in your case because you can then set the height of the parent element of the tab container to control the height of the ajax-loaded tabs.

Comment: Method what you suggested didn't help me. I tried this. Now sry for my bad english :)) Div had the same behavior as if I set `overflow: auto;`. Your method gave me an idea to set `min-height`. Now all fine. Thank you. Should I accept your answer? Edit it and I will accept. Or I will write my answer.

Comment: I will edit it with more information in the "fill" solution as it will have the same effect as what you did when I get back from lunch.